# JAXB resolution of complex types in JAX-WS web service

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-ws

I am facing an annoying error for a few days now regarding JAX-WS web-services. I intend to generate a web-service with methods that use custom types (basically structures of "JAX-WS primitive" types such as int, long and string) as parameters and return values.

This is the exception I get when trying to publish the web-service:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class
>   org.econet.ecomanager.msgexchange.webservice.SendMessageReqType do not
>   have a property of the name request   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:608)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createArgumentsBuilder(TieHandler.java:143)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.(TieHandler.java:115)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.(DatabindingImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:436)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:270)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:147)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:574)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:557)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:321)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:245)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:134)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)     at
>   org.econet.ecomanager.msgexchange.webservice.EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSideWSPublisher.main(EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSideWSPublisher.java:8)
>   Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: request is not a valid
>   property on class
>   org.econet.ecomanager.msgexchange.webservice.SendMessageReqType   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:985)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:596)
>     ... 16 more

The web-service interface is:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSide",
            targetNamespace="http://www.econet-cno.org/ecomsgexchange/ns",
            portName = "EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSidePort")
@BindingType (value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING)
public interface EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSide {

    @WebMethod(operationName="sendMessage")
    @RequestWrapper(className="org.econet.ecomanager.msgexchange.webservice.SendMessageReqType")
    @ResponseWrapper(className="org.econet.ecomanager.msgexchange.webservice.SendMessageRespType")
    @WebResult(name="sendMessageResp")
    public SendMessageRespType sendMessage(@WebParam(name="request") SendMessageReqType request);

...

}
```

The web-service implementation follows:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSideService",
            portName = "EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSidePort",
            targetNamespace="http://www.econet-cno.org/ecomsgexchange/ns",
            endpointInterface="org.econet.ecomanager.msgexchange.webservice.EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSide")
public class EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSideImpl implements EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSide {

    public SendMessageRespType sendMessage(SendMessageReqType request) {
        long messageId = sendMessage(request.getClientId(), request.getClientPassword(), request.getRecipientId(), 
                request.getFileName()+"."+request.getFileExtension(), request.getFileBytes());
        SendMessageRespType response = new SendMessageRespType();
        if(messageId != -1) {
            response.setMessageId(messageId);
            response.setSenderId(request.getRecipientId());
            response.setFileName(request.getFileName());
            response.setFileExtension(request.getFileExtension());
            return response;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

...

}
```

Classes SendMessageReqType and SendMessageRespType are just annotated with @XmlRootElement and have a bunch of atributes (protected) with getters and setters defined.

The problem is in JAXB that cannot interpret the data types in order to convert them to XML structures, but I have not been successful with all the attempts I made so far, trying different annotations. I searched a lot and almost all examples of JAX-WS available use only primitive types, the few ones that use complex types did not help either.

Anyone with an idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. In fact, it was the result from using multiple web service methods/operations with the same name, only changing the parameters bteween them. A Java like programming approach that is not acceptable when dealing with we services. After changing the methods names all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

By default JAX-WS parameter type is wrapped. So your params are already wrapped with some generated elements, like `sendMessage` and `sendMessageResponse`:

```
<xs:element name="sendMessage" type="tns:sendMessage"/>
<xs:element name="sendMessageResponse" type="tns:sendMessageResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="sendMessage">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="request" type="tns:sendMessageReqType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sendMessageReqType">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sendMessageResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sendMessageResp" type="tns:sendMessageRespType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sendMessageRespType">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>

<wsdl:message name="sendMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sendMessage" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sendMessageResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sendMessageResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

If you want to use your own wrapping elements instead of generated ones switch to Bare parameter style by adding `@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE)` to your SEI (i.e. EcoMsgExchangeSystemsSide) and remove @*Wrapper annotations (they don't make sense in this form). The result will be:

```
<xs:complexType name="sendMessageReqType">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sendMessageRespType">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="request" nillable="true" type="sendMessageReqType"/>
<xs:element name="sendMessageResp" nillable="true" type="sendMessageRespType"/>


<wsdl:message name="sendMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:request" name="request">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sendMessageResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sendMessageResp" name="sendMessageResp">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Thank you @dawid for your answer. In fact I don't want to replace generated wrapper classes by the ones I created, what I do want is to use complex types as parameters and return values. If I replace the wrappers generated by default I think that for the client each class attribute of `SendMessageReqType` will be assumed as a parameter of `sendMessage()`, am I right? In fact my problem is not the method parameters, I can use several of primitive types instead of a  complex type. The main problem is the return value, which I need to be more than one type, e.g. a file name and the file bytes.

Comment: I thought that you use `@*Wrapper` annotations to replace generated wrappers. This is the intention of those annotations. If you don't want to replace wrappers then you don't need those annotations. If you remove them then you get what you want - you will have wrapper type around your complex type classes. It would be easier to help you if you could specify what do you expect in terms of WSDL or SOAP message.

Comment: Sorry @dawid for this late feedback. I discovered the problem and it was kind of a newbie mistake. I was using different web service methods with the same, only with different parameters. Meanwhile I tried to change one of the names and voila! Problem solved.
Even though your answer was not what I needed I assume that, considereing my question desciption, it is a valid answer for that kind of problems. Should I mark it as accepted?

Comment: @tftdias - I'm happy to hear that you managed to tackle a problem :) Your original question was 
> Anyone with an idea of what am I doing wrong? 
If you feel I helped you pin down the problem then please accept the answer. If not you can still upvote the answer to appreciate my endeavours :) If you know more about a problem now you can also share with others what were symptoms (by editing question) and how you handled the problem (by adding your answer).

Comment: Thank you @dawid! Question answered.